# Browser Testing – Jquery Not Loading In IE8?

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser

The URL:
http://nomoresnoring.com/new/

What Browserstack.com says it looks like in IE9+ (nice!):
http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/1fa8063ad7510991811fbd280f61fd3f83a4ebf6/win7_ie_9.0.png

And in IE8 and earlier (uh oh):
http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/1fa8063ad7510991811fbd280f61fd3f83a4ebf6/win7_ie_8.0.png

What does this look like? Is jQuery not loading? How can I fix this?

Comment: FYI, I got 2 `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` on `mousewheel.js` && `easing.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a jQuery issue. You're using HTML5 elements which are not recognized by IE8 and lower.

You have to include [HTML5 shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/source/browse/trunk/html5-els.js?r=22) to make IE8 behave.

Comment: Aha! I was using Modernizr, but opted to leave it out. Would that save the same purpose?

Comment: Re-added Modernizr, which returned 95% of the structure. However, CSS3  classes are being ignored. Why is that?

Comment: IE8 and CSS3 - are you kidding? :D  Just as a reference - you can check the browser support for different CSS3 stuff here - http://caniuse.com/

Comment: Oh boy! More reasons to love IE :). Curious if http://css3pie.com is a reliable solution.

Comment: In 2013 it's OK for websites to lack all the bells and whistles in older browsers. I'd try to educate your client about IE8 usage and [graceful degradation](http://accessites.org/site/2007/02/graceful-degradation-progressive-enhancement/). But if that's absolutely not possible then css3pie may help somewhat

Answer (score 0):

Test it by going into the console and typing in either $.fn.jquery or $.ui.version. These commands should return what version of jquery (or lack of) the site is using.

Comment: I'm pulling the most current version via <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>. Is this incompatible with IE 6/7/8 for some reason?